how to init conda in google colab?
I have installed Conda in Google Collaboratory using the condacolab package.
I've also installed the packages from the environment.yml file.
However I still get an error when importing any of the packages installed from that file.
I don't quite understand whether contact collab will be initiated In the base environment by default or I have to run conda init.
This is one of the things I have tried:
!pip install -q condacolab
import condacolab
condacolab.install_miniconda() # expect a kernel restart
!conda env update -n base -f environment.yml

import some_package # errors

The import just returns "module not found."
Any ideas how to make this run? Is the conda base env activated under the hood?
I have check both the docs and the colab example file they provide.
